# How to get past the AttributeError in Gnu Radio version 3.8

Tags: python, c++, swig, attributeerror, gnuradio

Here is the error I am recieving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/awilhelmy5/Downloads/qpsk-adaptive-master/gnuradio/qpsk_usrp.py", line 354, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/awilhelmy5/Downloads/qpsk-adaptive-master/gnuradio/qpsk_usrp.py", line 332, in main
    tb = top_block_cls()
  File "/home/awilhelmy5/Downloads/qpsk-adaptive-master/gnuradio/qpsk_usrp.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.mapper_preamble_sync_demapper_hard_0 = mapper.preamble_sync_dehard(0, per_bits, mapper.QPSK, [0,1,3,2], 0, 3, False)
AttributeError: module 'mapper' has no attribute 'preamble_sync_dehard'
```

The very last line of the error is the part that is bugging me. I have tried a multitude of things, such as installing swig version 4.0, tried doing the sudo ldconfig command, tried reversing the order of the commands in the .h file, I changed the yml file name to match the name it had in the xml file and I even started messing around with the target_link
_libraries command. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your code has an error (e.g. accidental deletion of some characters)? I ask because I was not able to find the text "preamble_sync_dehard" anywhere on the web, but there *is* a class called [`gr::mapper::preamble_sync_demapper_hard`](https://github.com/gr-vt/gr-mapper/blob/master/include/mapper/preamble_sync_demapper_hard.h). Perhaps some person or program did an unwise find-and-replace that intended to remove a *prefix* `mapper_` but ended up removing a substring instead. You can check whether this is the problem: run Python and enter

```
import mapper
dir(mapper)
```

This will list all the names in the Python module, one of which (if this is the only problem) will be `preamble_sync_demapper_hard`, or some related spelling which you can then adjust your `qpsk_usrp.py` to use.

But if it is not there at all, then you may have a bigger problem. From what I have heard, OOT modules generally have to have their structure updated in order to work with GNU Radio 3.8, and [the repository I found](https://github.com/gr-vt/gr-mapper) doesn't seem to have been touched since 2018 (before 3.8 was released in 2019).

Comment: Gr-mapper has both python and C++ files, all I see when I run the command above is the python files, and none of the C++ ones. What would be your next step?

Comment: @arw150 I'm afraid I don't have any advice for further troubleshooting GR modules' integration. The usual advice is to (1) reinstall the module and (2) if it is not installed systemwide, make sure your library paths for both Python and C libraries match.